# How to use foreach() to iterate YQL XML and scrape HTML?

Tags: php, html, xml, yql

Wasn't sure what to call this, so I will quickly elaborate.

I have a screen scraper I am trying to build, using the [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) console.  The query provides the user with a choice of XML or JSON.  I am targeting the YQL>data>html aspect of the console, and chose XML as my output format.

My YQL Query:

> [SELECT * FROM html WHERE url="http://google.com"](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://google.com%22&diagnostics=true)

This will provide you with a readout of the Google.com document tree in XML. Too much output to paste into this post, so just click the link.

My problem comes with traversing the XML Tree with PHP to properly display the output from this request. I dont know how to effectively create a foreach statement (or any other statement) to effectively scrape the XML output and collect the Document tree and re-display it for my own needs.

My PHP:

```
$searchUrl = "google.com";

if(isset($_REQUEST['searchUrl'])) {
    $searchUrl = $_REQUEST['searchUrl'];
}

$query = "select * from html where url=\"http://".$searchUrl."\"";

$url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";

// Get Subcategory Article Data
$parameterData = "q=".urlencode($query);
$parameterData .= "&diagnostics=true";

// setup CURL 
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameterData); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

// send
$response = trim(urldecode(curl_exec($ch)));

// parse response
$xmlObjects = @simplexml_load_string($response);

foreach ($xmlObjects->diagnostics as $diagnostics) {
    echo "<a href=".$diagnostics->url." target='_blank'>".$diagnostics->url."</a>";
}
foreach ($xmlObjects->results as $result) {
    // here is where I would go echo $result->body or something along those lines
}
```

I suppose I am a bit stumped at this point due to my lack of knowledge to know where to turn next to navigate an XML tree with this type of format.  After `query>results>body` in the XML I am unsure where to turn to collect the remaining objects, and output it into my document in a `pre` tag or something of that nature.

I would like to provide an input field for users to enter their own domain, and my PHP will submit the query, iterate over the response, and return the Document tree to the user for HTML viewing and debugging.

I am familiar with PHP and XML in the context of iterating a large number of parent elements with the same internal structure like an RSS feed or something of that nature.  In this case I am dealing with a dynamic XML tree, with one large response object, and a fluctuating internal structure.

Comment: You'll actually not get the <head> section of the requested page, the YQL query only returns the body. Therefore no stylesheets and javascript requirements of the page are available. This will mess up the output in most cases. However, if you want to get the body as string use `echo $result->body->asXml();` (I assume you want a string)

Comment: Right, I was not overly interested in getting the `<head>` of the document, just the body.  Thanks for the reply, I will try your snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will display the result body as html page:

```
<?php

 // ... the code you posted in the question
 //     !without the diagnostics output!
 //     read comments of the answer to know why

?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<?php
foreach ($xmlObjects->results as $result) {
    // asXml() will return the content of body as xml string
    echo $result->body->asXml();
    break;
}
?>
</html>
```

Note that as you won't get the `<head>` element of the page via YQL the output will in most cases look messy.

Comment: Here is a [link to the output](http://pagespy.robabby.com/services.inc.php?searchUrl=google.com) I mentioned in response to you above, using your method.

Comment: Yes I told the output without scripts and styles will look messy. I tested it with my homepage and it looked at least readable. ( because of the fine  html code used ;) ) . In addition you should either remove the ouptut of diagnostics or use something like a frameset to separate the output from the displayed page. Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: You have definitely nudged me in the proper direction.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: You are welcome. Btw, I think YQL is very interesting stuff. Like it. Good luck!!